# GDB shows 'Cannot find bounds of current function' stepping

Tags: linux, gdb, vmware

We are running Linux Debian in VMWare. 
When debugging with gdb, if trying to step over memset/memcmp/strcmp etc... , gdb returns the following error:

```
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

We do not try to step into those c-functions, but only to step over them.
Any Ideas?

**EDITED:**

I add the sample code and compilation flags that causes the issue. It is probably related to running 32-bit executable on a 64-bit machine.

The versions are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux lavilinux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-         bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

$  gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
```

The sample failed code: **main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"

char* rb_my_exe;
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (strcmp(argv[0], "isgreat") == 0)
            printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The way I compiled it:

```
$ g++ -g -fexceptions -m32 -fstrict-aliasing -c -o main.o main.cpp
$ g++ -static -m32 -o main main.o
```

The result in gdb:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x80482dd: file main.cpp, line 9.
Starting program: /tmp/compile/main 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xffffd2d4) at main.cpp:9
9       if (strcmp(argv[0], "isgreat") == 0)
(gdb) n
0x080481b0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x080481b0 in ?? ()
#1  0x0804849f in __libc_start_main ()
#2  0x080481e1 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, i I understand, you are using the "next" command? Could you give us the GDB version, GCC version, a simple program example and the command line used to compile ?

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue. Fixed it by tracking memory access

Answer (score 0):

It seems the cause of this issue is that I'm trying to debug 32-bit programs with 64-bit gdb.
I havn't tried it, but I think I need to compile gdb in 32-bit mode, and try to debug it again.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, I tried to compile for 32 bit, but still no help...